# Error while creating xamarin.forms shared project

Tags: xamarin

I'm using Visual Studio 15 on windows and I've installed xamarin on it. I'm trying to create app for cross platform but encountering an error while doing so.
When I'm clicking on `File->new->project->cross platform->xamarin.forms shared project` and then `create` ,but I'm getting a pop message saying

> A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'app4'.The imported
>   project "C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindoesXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets

please get me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

When i take the error i try to use JDK 1.7 and my problem have solved. Have you tried targeting JDK 1.7~ ?

I follow under steps and when i use on ProjectName.Droid, i dont any error.

File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Cross-Platform -> Blank App(Native Shared)

<-- When i use under source and i take errors that titles. -->

File -> New Project -> Visual C# -> Android -> Blank App

So please try, first step.

Comment: It's working fine with blank app(native shared), but I'm interested to work in blank app(xamarin.forms shared) and its showing error while creating xamarin.forms shared application.